# Transactional File Copy

Tags: windows, copy, utility

*Does anyone know of a program for Windows Server 2008, Windows 7, etc. that allows you to do the following:*

Automatically replaces the Windows copy feature with improved features allowing you to:

- Copy files from A to B with the ability to shutdown/restart your machine mid-process ... upon restart it resumes
- Allows you to pause copying
- Allows you to start other copies that are queued if other copies are taking place

Something like this would a lifesaver.

Regards.

Comment: This is definitely a serverfault question.

Comment: Sorry, will push these to Serverfault going forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [TeraCopy](http://www.codesector.com/download.php) from CodeSector.

I'm not sure about the shutdown/restart of the machine and continuing, but it covers the other features you're looking for.